# Abbreviation 'p.e.p' on postcard from 1928

Tags: abbreviations, twentieth-century-english

[image: Note]I am a first year History and English BA student in Devon, England. I am currently writing an essay examining primary sources, one of which is a postcard. I was wondering if you were able to offer any light on the content of the message written on it?
The note says:

> This is where we had lunch yesterday, the most wonderful view you can imagine - this doesn't give any idea of it but we were unable to get any more p.e.p.

I was wondering if you had any idea what *p.e.p.* stands for/refers to? It is a black and white photographic postcard from 1928.

[image: POSTCARD]

Comment: Properly Exposed Photos/Postcards?

Comment: I thought it could be something along those lines. Do you know this to be a term that would have been commonly used during that period or is this just speculation?! :)

Comment: Not at all, never seen it before. Just guessing at something that might make sense.

Comment: What is the photo of?

Comment: It is a photographic image of the coast of a local seaside town, with an arrow pointing to the location of a hotel on the cliff. It looks like it was taken from the air.

Comment: Perhaps 'perfectly' for 'properly'.

Comment: From 1902 to appx 1940 something, people were making postcards using an Eastman process called RPPC--Real Photo Postcards. Mabe the writer was confused about the name?

Comment: I would love to but I can't work out how to?!!

Comment: Are you sure it's not simply the initials of the sender?

Comment: No, underneath it says 'Love M'.

Comment: What coast, what local seaside town, which hotel? Is it a famous cliff? Which country? (Can you take a photo of the postcard with your phone?)

Comment: @Clare There we are, sorry, it wasn't that I didn't have a photo. I just couldn't work out how to upload it! Doh!

Comment: Ooh, that’s terribly small—isn’t there a bigger version that’s more legible?

Comment: Definitely needs to be larger, I'm afraid: what's visible in that shot looks like p.g.m. to me.

Comment: Is that better? Sorry, not too good at this!

Comment: Maybe _"We were unable to get any more **pictures**"_

Comment: The abbreviation reads like p.s.p, seemingly suggesting postcard size photos.

Comment: @Bethany does it look like *pics* or *pcs*?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be p.c.s, standing for postcards. The first letter is clearly "p". The third letter looks like the writer's "s"s, particularly the one in "yesterday". The second letter doesn't particularly look like anything in the alphabet, but I can imagine it being a very badly formed "c".

Answer (score 0):

It might be

**pics.**

Short for *pictures*. Hard to tell exactly in a photo of this  resolution. The *i* in *pics* either lacks a dot or the dot is over the next letter  (*c*). Other *i's* may have the same feature.

Instead, if it is initials (three letters), it could be

**p.c.s.**

presumably short for *postcards*.

Comment: All the other words are in cursive and have their letters joined together. This one is three clearly separate letters, and so likely to be an abbreviation.

Comment: @Peter What are the three letters?

Comment: That's a very good question. They look like p. s. r. to me, but the p. is the only one I'm sure about. It might even be p. c. s. — postcards.